# Android Studio App Unfortunately has stopped

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android and I was practicing, when i finished this practice app i ran it but it says "unfortunately has stopped" where is the problem?My app looks like a simple log in screen and i don't think there's a problem with the XML file.

```
package com.mycompany.testbutton;

import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Button buttonLog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
EditText userName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameText);
EditText passWord = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordText);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    buttonLog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String username = String.valueOf(userName.getText());
            String password = String.valueOf(passWord.getText());
            String allTogetherToast = "Your Email is " + username + " and your Password is " + password;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, allTogetherToast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: call `findViewById` after `setContentView`

Comment: For Android's sake post the error in `Logcat`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize these

```
Button buttonLog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
EditText userName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameText);
EditText passWord = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
```

after your

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

so your code will be like this

```
package com.mycompany.testbutton;

import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Button buttonLog; 
EditText userName; 
EditText passWord;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
buttonLog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
userName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameText);
passWord = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordText);


buttonLog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String username = String.valueOf(userName.getText());
        String password = String.valueOf(passWord.getText());
        String allTogetherToast = "Your Email is " + username + " and your Password is " + password;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, allTogetherToast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
});
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();

//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Move

```
Button buttonLog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
EditText userName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameText);
EditText passWord = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
```

after `setContentView(....)` inside **onCreate(...)**

### Corrected:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button buttonLog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
EditText userName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameText);
EditText passWord = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
```

`Views` available only after `setContentView(....)`